# MySQL BMI calculation

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the BMI of a member and save it in the database. They can then just view their stored BMI.

Below is the only thing that I can came up with but there's some error in the codes (mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in).

Could someone help me fix it?

```
$bmi= mysql_query ("SELECT id WHERE ((SELECT (weight)) / ((SELECT (height)) * (SELECT (height))) FROM myMembers) FROM myMembers");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($bmi)){ 
$sqlUpdate = mysql_query("UPDATE myMembers SET bmi='$bmi' WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Comment: When your code throws errors, **post the error message**.

Comment: You might need to add a blank column before you fill it with update. I'm not sure offhand.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, (weight / height * height) as bmi FROM myMembers
```

Comment: thanks for the help!
But how can I save the result into table myMembers?

Comment: Are you sure? Could 100/5*5 = 100, instead of 4 ?

Comment: It's ok, I just have problems with mySQL, it's doesn't matter how the math. 
All I need to know is how I can calculate two fields in a table and store the result in the same table.
The Query works well but it didn't store in or update the table.

Answer (score 1):

The deal with SQL is you want to reduce the number of quires as much as possible.  sub-selects should be avoided,  but its a lot better than breaking it up into a ton of queries.  doing a while() over a select should be avoided like herpes.

`update myMember set bmi=weight/(height*height)`

And this will set the entire column for all users.  But really this is a hack it should be done on insert or with a trigger.